# Remove Characters From A String Until A Specific Format is Reached

Tags: python, string, split, str-replace

So I have the following strings and I have been trying to figure out how to manipulate them in such a way that I get a specific format.

```
string1-itd_jan2021-internal
string2itd_mar2021-space
string3itd_feb2021-internal
string4-itd_mar2021-moon
string5itd_jun2021-internal
string6-itd_feb2021-apollo
```

I want to be able to get rid of any of the last string so I am just left with the month and year, like below:

```
string1-itd_jan2021
string2itd_mar2021
string3itd_feb2021
string4-itd_mar2021
string5itd_jun2021
string6-itd_feb2021
```

I thought about using string.split on the - but then realized that for some strings this wouldn't work. I also thought about getting rid of a set amount of characters by putting it into a list and slicing but the end is varying characters length?

Is there anything I can do it with regex or any other python module?

Comment: Is it possible for a string to have multiple months in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with the appropriate `maxsplit` parameter:

```
s = s.rsplit("-", 1)[0]
```

You could also use `str.split` (even though this is clearly the worse choice):

```
s = "-".join(s.split("-")[:-1])
```

Or using regular expressions:

```
s = re.sub(r'-[^-]*$', '', s)
# "-[^-]*" a "-" followed by any number of non-"-"
```

Comment: It's because I just did str.split not rsplit. I never knew it existed. Sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: `re.sub(r'-?itd', '_itd', s)` ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) like so:

```
import re
lines = '''string1-itd_jan2021-internal
string2itd_mar2021-space
string3itd_feb2021-internal
string4-itd_mar2021-moon
string5itd_jun2021-internal
string6-itd_feb2021-apollo'''

for old in lines.split('\n'):
    new = re.sub(r'[-][^-]+$', '', old)
    print('\t'.join([old, new]))
```

Prints:

```
string1-itd_jan2021-internal    string1-itd_jan2021
string2itd_mar2021-space        string2itd_mar2021
string3itd_feb2021-internal     string3itd_feb2021
string4-itd_mar2021-moon        string4-itd_mar2021
string5itd_jun2021-internal     string5itd_jun2021
string6-itd_feb2021-apollo      string6-itd_feb2021
```

Explanation:
`r'[-][^-]+$'` : Literal dash (`-`), followed by any character other than a dash (`[^-]`) repeated 1 or more times, followed by the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score -1):

With a regex:

```py
import re
re.sub(r'([0-9]{4}).*$', r'\1', s)
```